# set controllers using custom role provider in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I am new to custom role providers and roles. I need to show some functionalities in the home page.

- If Admin enters the page it will show some button like delete, alter.
- If Normal user login the home page it will show some features like view and update but it will not shows the delete and alter functionalists.

I can do this using JavaScript but **I need to implement this by using custom role provider**. Is it possible using MVC4?

I have searched lots of websites but I did not find out how to do it. Can anyone give me some examples for this.

Comment: You definitely should not rely on Javascript to hide admin functions in your frontend code that still would work on the server side if they were visible.

Comment: OK but I need to show delete and update functionalities only for ADMIN role. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can include admin areas in your view with razor like that:

```
@{if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        <text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Index", "Admin", null, new { @class = currentPage == "admin-index" ? "currentPage" : "" });
        </text>
    }
}
```

In your controller you should make sure that admin settings and command that get sent (via Ajax post, e.g.) in come frome an authenticated admin user. Just an example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AccessDeniedAuthorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public JsonResult SaveOrder(int StationId, string ca, string items)
    {
         ...[your code]...
    }
```

Comment: Can you give some website addresses for references.